# Permissions for web services account

Tags: sql, sql-server, web-applications

I'm trying to secure the web service account that connects to the web app. I wanted to know what is the best practice for what permission the account should have? Should the web service have execute all or should the access be limited?

I've tried to limit the access by assigning only the stored procedures and schema it needs but that requires updating the access every time a new stored procedure is added. Is this best practice or should the account just have execute all?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create a new database role in SQL Server like this:

```
CREATE ROLE db_executor;
```

The name of the role is really up to you - since you have `db_reader` and `db_writer` already, this `db_executor` seems quite fitting - but that's entirely your choice.

and then grant this role execute permissions on all **existing AND future** stored procedures like this:

```
GRANT EXECUTE TO db_executor;
```

This is a role now that will *automagically* get execute permission on any - even **future!** - stored procedure (and function) that you might create in your SQL Server database.